# Microsoft Cognitive Emotion API error in Azure Functions

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-functions

I'm following tutorial on http://martinabbott.azurewebsites.net/2016/06/11/fun-with-azure-functions-and-the-emotion-api/    
Finally got solvet issue with blob trigger.  I have verified that my jpg file can be succesfully processed with my API key in the Open API Test console. I have upload project.json file include dependancies to "Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Emotion": "1.0.251"

I'm getting now error. How to solve?

2016-11-07T06:53:44.951 C# Blob Emotion function processed: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob
2016-11-07T06:53:45.076 Function completed (Failure, Id=c0c50024-7830-4595-b749-56f58ec79d0b)
2016-11-07T06:53:45.107 Exception while executing function: Functions.BlobTriggerEmotionFunction. Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Common: Exception of type 'Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Common.ClientException' was thrown.

Comment: This is a duplicate of: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/9dc41eb8-c419-4da2-bc21-09212791851a/error-when-calling-microsoftprojectoxford-on-azure-functions?forum=AzureFunctions, which has been answered.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the tutorial you are referencing, for the line of code,

```
var apiKey = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EMOTION_API_KEY"];
```

did you set the EMOTION_API_KEY in your Function app's App settings?

You may verify with the following steps:

1. Visit your Function app through the Functions portal.
2. Click **Function app settings -> Configure app settings**.
3. Verify that the `EMOTION_API_KEY` exists and that its value matches the one you used in the Open API Test console.